# Osm2pgsql: Error Loading in north-america-latest.osm.pbf

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I've had my OSM Tile server working great for several days now, but just with Indiana. I decided to fill the gis database with all of North America.
I run the following command:

```
sudo -u user osm2pgsql --slim -d gis -C 2000 number-processes 3 /usr/local/share/maps/planet/north-america-latest.osm.pbf
```

After Running I get this Error:

```
  Using built-in tag processing pipeline
  Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
  Setting up table: planet_osm_point
  Setting up table: planet_osm_line
  Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
  Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
  Allocating memory for dense node cache
  Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
  Allocating memory for sparse node cache
  Sharing dense sparse
  Node-cache: cache=2000MB, maxblocks=256000*8192, allocation method=11
  Mid: pgsql, scale=100 cache=2000
  Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
  Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
  Setting up table: planet_osm_rels

  Reading in file: number-processes
  error while opening file number-processes
```

I've searched the internet for about 2 hours now and can't find anything useful. Maybe I'm missing some key information. Anyone ran into this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in you call. `number-processes` is an option, so you should use `--number-processes`